# In my Android app as splash screen disappears, next screen becomes black

Tags: android, android-studio

**This is my SplashActivity class.** 
In my Android app I've used a splash screen. But as splash screen disappears, then next screen becomes black before switching to main activity. So, how can I prevent that black screen?

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

RegisterGCM registerGCM;
private GpsTracker1 mGps;
boolean canLocate;
public static boolean appVisible = false;

public static String lat;

public static String lon;

public static String addr;

public static String addr1;

public static String city;

public static String state;

public static String pin;

public static String country;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    this.mGps = new GpsTracker1(this);
    canLocate = mGps.canGetLocation();

    if (!canLocate)
    {
        this.mGps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    else
    {
        getGpsInfo();
    }
}


public void getGpsInfo()
{
    registerGCM = new RegisterGCM(getApplicationContext());
    String regId = registerGCM.getRegistrationId();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
    {
        registerGCM.registerGCM();
    }


    lat = this.mGps.getLatitude();
    lon = this.mGps.getLongitude();
    addr = this.mGps.getAddress();
    addr1 = this.mGps.getAddress1();
    city = this.mGps.getCity();
    state = this.mGps.getState();
    pin = this.mGps.getPostalcode();
    country = this.mGps.getCountry();


    Thread timerThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                sleep(2000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Category_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
}

public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    appVisible = true;
}
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    appVisible = false;
}
```

}

Comment: try to perform getGpsInfo() on separate thread and it should also be checked that you are not performing any heavy task on main thread in main activity

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you post your runnable instead of blocking a thread?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Category_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);

    // Other details
}
```

It starts your activity in the main thread.

Comment: i have tried this but no solution. Problem still persist.

Comment: any other solution ?